# I get an error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I get this error, and i'm a beginner in this coding so i don't know much. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>   1
using namespace std;  2
int a,b,k,i,n,c;      3
int main()            4
{                     5  
cin>>a>>b;            6
 k=0;                 7 
 for (i=a;i<=b;i=i+1) 8
{                     9    
    n=i;              10
    c=0;              11                        
    while (n>0)       12
    {                 13
        if (n%2=1)    14
            c=c+1;    15
        n=n/10;       16
    }                 17
    if (c>0)          18
        k=k+1;        19
}                     20               
cout<<k;              21
                      22
return 0;             23
}                     24
```

The error appears to be at row 14!
I'm using Code::Blocks Version 13.12

Comment: You *do* know the difference between assignment and comparison for equality? You're doing the first (assignment).

Comment: Just a typo. Know the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: `if (n%2=1)` is giving the value 1 to `n%2`. Conceptually, this doesn't make sense. You meant `if (n%2==1)` with the compare operator.

Comment: OMG... i'm so stupid... =))), thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a single '=' on row 14, but that is only for assignment. You are doing an if comparison, so you must use '=='.

```
if (n % 2 == 1)
```

Comment: Please don't answer such questions. They are not useful to a general audience.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm still new at this, I will bear this in mind

Comment: There is a vote to close option for such simple typographical errors.

Comment: Can i just delete the question or what? =))

Comment: @SweetPopcorn, sure can.